# Exclude certain headings from numbering in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer, table-of-contents

I have a document with headings on multiple levels and a table of contents.
Each heading is numbered:

```
1
1.1
1.1.1
etc
```

And they are all present in my Table of Contents.
What I want to do is to remove the numbering from some of the headings, but keep them in the table of contents.

I can't remove the numbering for that particular heading level, as other chapter headers use it and will require numbering.

I tried to create a second Heading style, without numbering, but then my chapter isn't counted in the Table of Contents.

What can I do to be able to just remove the numbering from specific chapter headers in LibreOffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach to add a custom "heading" style without numbering is correct, you just need to **add it to the ToC**.

You can do this by editing the ToC properties. Assuming you've inserted the ToC already, right-click inside the ToC and select "Edit Index". A dialogue similar to the following should appear:

[image: ToC Properties dialogue]

Make sure to activate "Additional styles" below "**Create from**", and click on <kbd>Assign styles...</kbd> button:

[image: Assign Styles dialogue]

1. Select your custom heading style from the Styles list in the leftmost column labeled "Not applied".
2. Use the arrow buttons to move that style to the appropriate heading level. In my example, the style "Heading w/o Numbering" would appear on level 5 in my ToC.